# Switch Overlay Specification in Latex Beamer

Tags: latex, beamer, bibliography

I have a beamer document with

```
\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}
```

in the preamble to make `\items` appear separately. However, this seems to also make `\bibitem`s
appear separately. How can I switch back to 'normal' within the document, such that all bibitems appear on one slide?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the default overlay specification before the bibliography:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
\item content...
\item content...
\end{itemize}
\end{frame}

\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{}

\begin{frame}
\nocite{knuth:ct,angenendt}
\printbibliography
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]